# Setting up Raindrop

Tags: windows-7, raindrop

I've installed Raindrop on Win7 and it's running - the problem is I cannot get it to load my .raindrop configuration file to get my account information. I think I'm placing the .raindrop file in the wrong place, but the documentation isn't spelling it out quite clearly enough for my old brain. Here's what it says:

> ...you want to use in raindrop via a
> .raindrop file:
>
> configure raindrop by
> editing ~/.raindrop

I've set up my .raindrop file (there wasn't one anywhere I could find in the installation dir). In windows, the only way I know to name a file without an extension is to ALT+255 the file name - could that be causing the problem?

Anyone know what directory the ~ above is referring to?

Comment: voting to close- i was thinking it would be programming related since I plan to play with the source but the question itself isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The .raindrop file needed to be placed in my home dir (I know, stupid windows user).

The code was that was looking for it:

```
filename = [os.path.expanduser('~/.raindrop')]
```

Answer (score 1):

~ is the users home directory.  On windows 7 (provided everything is working) it should be C:\Users\username

You can save a file without the annoyances by using quotes in the save as dialog (on notepad at least).  For instance ".raindrop".